# Scaling and Shifting Scipy Distributions in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

I am working with `scipy.stats.beta` to generate a Beta distribution probability density function.

You can see the expected result for the standard interval of [0,1] here:
[image]

I would like to create the distribution on the interval [-1,1] instead. For `a,b = 0.5, 0.5` one would expect the "u" shaped curve to distribute with the mean at 0 and ending at [-1,1]. However, with `std = 1` and `mean = 0` I get the following:
[image]

Now, if I set `mean = -1` and `std = 2` then I get close to what the desired result is:
[image]

Why is the PDF not scaling / centering as expected using the standard deviation and mean inputs? I must not be understanding the controls for the distribution function.

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)

#x = np.linspace(beta.ppf(0.01, a, b),beta.ppf(0.99, a, b), 100)
x = np.arange(-1.0,1.0,0.01)

a, b = 0.5,0.5 #2.31, 0.627
mean = -1
std = 2
#mean, var, skew, kurt = beta.stats(a, b, moments='mvsk')
pdf = beta.pdf(x, a, b, loc=mean, scale=std)

ax.plot(x, pdf,'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='beta pdf')

mean = np.nanmean(pdf[np.isfinite(pdf)]) 
std = np.nanstd(pdf[np.isfinite(pdf)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters `loc` and `scale` are *not* the mean and standard deviation of the distribution.  They are translation and scaling parameters; see, e.g. ["Location-scale family"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family).  For the beta distribution, `loc` is the left end of the support interval, and `scale` is its length.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html):

> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale parameters. Specifically, `beta.pdf(x, a, b, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to `beta.pdf(y, a, b) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

So when you are using `scale = 1` and `loc = 0`, you are simply getting the distribution `beta.pdf(x, a, b)`, which you can really verify.

The reason why you get the first plot is that you are trying to plot a Beta distribution over an `x` domain that contains zero and `Beta(0, 0.5, 0.5)` tends to Infinity.

Note that you don't see the distribution exploding at the right side of your plot because your `x.max() == 0.99`